# can't display multiple checkbox save value in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't display Multiple checkbox save value in my view page.
Here is the insert/save value details:

### Model:

```
public function saveInstituteOfferdCourse($data = array()) 
{
        if ($this->db->insert('tbl_course_offred', $data)) 
    {
        return $this->db->insert_id(); // tbl_course_offred = "Table name"
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

### Controller:

```
public function saveCourses() 
{
    $data = array();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('skill', 'skill', 'require');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) 
    {
        $skill = implode(',', $this->input->post('skill'));
        $data['skill'] = $skill;
        $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->user_admin_model->saveInstituteOfferdCourse($data);
        redirect("user_admin_controller/showInsSkills");
    }
}
```

### View:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="tambah">
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="PHP" >PHP</input
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="VB.NET" >VB.NET</input
<input type="checkbox" name="skill[]" value="C#" >C#</input
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to display value like below site courses.
http://www.yet5.com/training-institute/yet5/5955/coimbatore/mazenet-gandhipuram-at-gandhipuram.html

Comment: what are you trying to do? Are you trying to display the values saved in a table column?

Comment: Please embed a screenshot of the desired display; don't rely on external link.

Answer (score 0):

It's 'required', not 'require' (in the controller). Try to test your form_validation function. Try to remove form_validation at all and see if it works.

Also, please don't save comma separated values in a database column. Create a new table with a row that couples skill_id and user_id (so if a user has 3 skills, this table would contain 3 rows).

Comment: Hi, Rahel Ahan,Thanks for advising.I honor your advise,Can give me any idea how can save withour comma separated. please

Comment: (replace \n with an enter, I can't get that to work in the comment box)Ok, suppose you have a table like this:\n
id|name|stuff\n
1|John|2,3,4\n
Where stuff is comma separated. Then you create a new table with the following:\n

Id|name_id|stuff_id\n
1|1|2\n
2|1|3\n
3|1|4\n
\n
So each value in the stuff column gets its separate row in your new table. Then you can query the second table. It's a bit more work in te beginning, but will save you LOTS of time in the long run. Good luck!